# Find triplets from the array(X1,X2,Y), such that X1*X2=Y^2

Tags: algorithm

How to find *triplets*, form an *array* ,

(X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub>, Y),

such that

X<sub>1</sub> * X<sub>2</sub> = Y<sup>2</sup>

There can't be any repetition in the result and the elements are in a range of 10<sup>5</sup>

I have tried doing it, by *taking all combinations*, but I want an *efficient approach* ...

Comment: Can `x1, x2, y` *repeat*? E.g. for `{1, 1, 2, 3}` is `1*1 == 1**2` a valid solution? Note that we have `3` `1`s in the solution but only `2` in the array

Comment: repeatitions aren't allowed

Comment: look for Bounds, if x is the same there should only be one ratio solution. Sqrt(3x) = y

Comment: @RussianBoy - What's the range of the array values?

Comment: @armali the range is 100000

Comment: This is probably [3SUM-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM#3SUM-hardness).

Comment: @RussianBoy What is the max possible size of the array?

Comment: @RussianBoy First, please be online or hang around if someone is trying to help you. Second, are duplicates not present in the input array or do you not want this in the final output? Also, are `x1,x2,y` supposed to be of different indices `i,j,k` where `i != j != k` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a number Y <= 100000 can have at most 6 distinct prime factors, each Y<sup>2</sup> will have less than 4064 factor pairs.  On average, about 100.

That leads to an O(N) algorithm...  It has a factor of x000 in it, but it will still be faster than the O(N<sup>2</sup>) solutions for large inputs:

1. Build a hashmap that gives the frequency for each number in the array (O(N))
2. For each number Y, completely factorize it, and generate each possible pair of factors for Y<sup>2</sup>.  To factorize Y, trial division by primes less than 316 is fine.
3. For each pair, check the frequency table to see if they both appear in addition to Y.  Note that Y is a factor of Y<sup>2</sup>, and for this one you have to check to see if Y appears at least 3 times.

Also, you only need to check the keys of the hashmap, and there are at most 100000 of those.  Even if every number <= 100000 is in the array, there are less than 7M factor pairs to check.

Comment: How do you pass from factors of Y to factors of Y^2 in O(1)? For example factors of 6: {1,2,3,6}, couples: {(1,6), (2,3)}. Then factors of 36: {1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36}, couples: {(1,36), (2,8), (3,12), (4,9), (6,6)}

Comment: How about the memory requirements? considering an array of { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18 };

Comment: You don't need to remember all the factorizations or factor pairs.  Check them as you generate them, so there's only the hash map that's of any significant size

Answer (score 1):

A python implementation (more compact and readable) of the [Dmitry solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60207998/10863549) that cost O(N^2)

```py
import math
input_list = [1,2,18,7,6,22,4,8,65]
squared_y = {x**2 for x in input_list} #this will be a set with O(1) lookup
solution = set()
for index, x1 in enumerate(input_list):
    for x2 in input_list[index+1:]:
        if x1 * x2 in squared_y:
            solution.add((x1,x2))
            solution.add((x2,x1))
for sol in solution:
    if sol[0] <= sol[1]:
        print(sol[0], sol[1], int(math.sqrt(sol[0]*sol[1])), sep=", ")
```

Result:

```py
2, 18, 6
2, 8, 4
1, 4, 2
```

Comment: You might also want to eliminate duplicate triplets.

Comment: @vivek_23 OP stated there is no repetition so there won't be any repetition

Comment: @vivek_23 1 (as x1) is an element of the array, 4 (as x2) is an element of the array, 4 (as y^2) is the square of the element 2. I don't see any repetition

Comment: @MarcoZamboni [See here for repetition of triplets](https://onlinegdb.com/Bk9LspzX8)

Comment: @vivek_23 Your input contains 3 different ones, OP said that there isn't any repetition...

Comment: @MarcoZamboni I think he mean't no duplicates in the final output, as the first comment asks for _Can x1, x2, y repeat_ with an answer of _no_. (...clarifying from OP).

Comment: @vivek_23 ok, modified accordingly

Comment: @Armali I see the question ask for X1, X2 and Y so I'll edit to match it

Answer (score 1):

Using `HashMap` of Java,

taking all pairs of `x1, x2` from the array and inserting into the Map as `[y, [x1, x2]]` only when `x1*x2` is a square. That eliminates many combinations, reduces memory requirements and less comparison for the later part.

Then loop through the Map key values matching with the array elements.

This is `O(n^2)` timing complexity.

```
public class FindTriplets
{
   final static int isSquare(long n)
   {
      int tst = (int) (Math.sqrt(n) + 0.5);
      if ((tst * tst) == n)
         return tst;
      else
         return 0;
   }

   static void findTriplets(int[] nums)
   {
      Map<Integer, List<Integer>> triplets = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();

      int n = nums.length;

      // insert into a Map as {y, [x1, x2]} when y*y = x1*x2, x1 & x2 are elements of nums
      for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
      {
         for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
         {
            int y = isSquare(nums[i] * nums[j]);
            if (y != 0)
            {
               List<Integer> x1x2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(nums[i], nums[j]));
               triplets.put(y, x1x2);
            }
         }
      }

      // Now look for elements nums[i] matching with y in the Map

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
         if (triplets.containsKey(nums[i]))
         {
            List<Integer> x1x2 = triplets.get(nums[i]);    
            System.out.println(x1x2.toString() + " -> " + nums[i]);
         }
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[] num = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18 };
      findTriplets(num);    
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[2, 8] -> 4
[4, 9] -> 6
[4, 16] -> 8
[9, 16] -> 12
```