# Searching triplets in two arrays

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search

Given two arrays a and b of size `n`. I have to choose one element from a and two elements from b such that. `a[i] * a[i] = b[j] * b[k]`.

I am able to find BruteForce in `O(n^2 log(n))` traversing both the arrays and binary searching the value. But dont know how to improve it even more.

How do I count all these number where elements range from `1 <= a[i] <= 10^6` and `1 <= n <= 10^6`.

Comment: If they're integers (rather than floating-point numbers you need to compare with an error tolerance), you could store the squares of `a` in a hashtable to look up in O(1) time instead of O(log n) time. That gets it down to O(n + m^2) where m is the length of b, which is probably about as good as you can do, because the problem is so similar to [3SUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM#3SUM-hardness).

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207700/find-triplets-from-the-arrayx1-x2-y-such-that-x1x2-y2#comment106494073_60207700) is not an exact duplicate, but the answers there should work for your problem.

Comment: Get all factors of a[i] * a[i] by going from 1 till a[i]. Check if these factors exists in B by pre-adding all values of B in map. Gets little tricky with duplicates, but you can maintain a count to overcome this.

Comment: Consider accepting an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I can think in a O(n²) solution.

```
unordered_multiset S = {}
for each element B in b {
    S = S ∪ B
}
```

First of all, we store all elements of `b` in a `unordered_multiset`. Such structure can find elements in O(1) time and if you add 2 or more equal elements, it also knows.

```
for each element B in b {
    for each element A in a {
        if( A² % B != 0 ) continue;                            //making sure it's divisible
        let occurrencies = number_of_occurrencies(A² / B, S);
        if( occurrencies > 0 ) {                               //if (A² / B) is in S
            if( A == B and ocurrencies > 1 ) {
                //your answer is A, B and B
            }
            else if ( A != B ) {
                //your answer is A, B and A² / B
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here you loop over both arrays. The main goal is to check, for each element in `b`, which elements it must be multiplied for in order to be equal to some element of `a` squared. The, it checks if the element `B` needs is already in `S`.

There is a little trick in that. If `A = 30` and `B = 30`, it means that you want to have another 30 in `b` who's not `B`. That's the reason of the multiset. If there is only one 30 in the whole set, you know that you are trying to match `B` with itself, and you can't do that, hence you have to have at least 2 elements valued 30 in `b`.

Comment: Integer division could lead to false result, 8*8 = 64, now say in b there are 6 and 10, 64/6 = 10, so we got 8, 6, 10 which is wrong.

Comment: Edited to fix this case.